# Nginx and passenger 3.0.0 on mac - why does it fail on startup?

Tags: nginx, passenger

I've been trying to set up nginx 0.8.53 and passenger 3.0.0 on my dev
environment - osx snow leopard and REE.  I manually compiled nginx
with the passenger module linked in.

When I tried running passenger, it had a problem - ENV['PATH']
appeared to be null, so the split on it when call
PlatformInfo.find_command raised an exception.  It was called when
trying to find out the osname - looking for the sw_vers command.

I tweaked the source and told it that it was macosx and then it
complained that it couldn't find the Rails 2.3.8 gem.  This is
probably related to the first problem.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this?  When I su -i and sudo nobody,
both users let me start irb and see the expected value for
ENV['PATH'], so I'm not sure why it's not working when passenger is
running?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: Passenger launches as the user that owns the config/environment.rb file (or of the config.ru file, if you have one) - make sure that file's owner is something sensible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you start Nginx, but you can write a launcher script for Nginx that starts Nginx with a specific environment, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=whatever
exec /path/to/nginx
```